# What does 何もいません mean?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand the dialogue 5:03 in [this tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euKqlJWhQXE&list=PLB3F2C5D8B5F81F34).
What I'm hearing is this:

> なにがいますか。
>
> なにもいませんね。
>
> あれ。ねこがいますよ。
>
> え、どこに？
>
> あそこにいますよ。

The lesson is about how to say that something is somewhere and the differences between います/あります。 So the video goes on to explain the last three sentences.

The first sentence, I think, means something like: "Who's/what's there?". However, I don't understand that the second means. I know も is used for "also", so all I came up with was the nonsensical

What too isn't there, is there?

Please help :)

Comment: 何もいません strikes me as a strange animate/inanimate construction. 何もありません or 誰もいません sound better to me. Any takers?

Comment: @dainichi If they were asking the question specifically with animals in mind, wouldn't it be okay?  何 rather than 誰 for animals, but います because they're animate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This use of the `も` expresses *completeness or totality*, like the English word *all*.  And in particular, when it's attached to an *indefinite demonstrative* (なに, どこ, どれ, だれ, どなた, and so on), it causes that word to refer to a **complete set** of the type denoted by the demonstrative:

```
　　だれ　　　who
　　だれも　　everyone   (with positive verb)
　　だれも　　no one     (with negative verb)
```

The same thing happens when you add も to other words like this:

```
　　どこ　　　where
　　どこも　　everywhere (with positive verb)
　　どこも　　nowhere    (with negative verb)
```

```
　　どれ　　　which
　　どれも　　all        (with positive verb)
　　どれも　　none       (with negative verb)
```

But なに is an exception.  It doesn't usually appear in positive sentences:

```
　　なに　　　what
　　なにも　　everything (with positive verb)
　　なにも　　nothing    (with negative verb)
```

So let's make things easier to understand by starting with an example that's **not** an exception.  We'll use だれ, which means *who*, and we'll add も to that to make *everyone*.  Here it is with a positive verb:

> [ **だれも** ] が　知っています【しっています】
>   [ **everyone** ] knows

And now, with a negative verb:

> [ **だれも** ] いません。
>   [ **no one** ] is here.

Why does the meaning change with a negative verb?  Well, it doesn't really.  The example above literally means "**Everyone** is not here", but the usual way to say that in English is with the logically equivalent "**No one** is here".

Okay, so now let's try a sentence with **なにも**.  Like I said before, this is an exception, so we'll skip making a positive sentence and go straight to the negative:

> [ **なにも** ] ありません。
>   [ **nothing** ] is there.

This literally means "**Everything** is not there".   But again, that's not how we usually say it in English, so we translate it instead to the logically equivalent "**Nothing** is there".  And your sentence is the same, except that it uses います (animate existence) rather than あります (inanimate existence).

Comment: 何もかも essentially serves as the positive 何も, oddly enough (although it's perhaps a little more intense than the other positive 〜も words).

Comment: Thanks, snailboat! Can you please explain why in the positive sentence you used the subject-marker ga, while in the negative sentence you omitted it?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Well, usually you don't use が with も like that.  I think that the reason it's okay here, is that in positive sentences `だれも` is usually treated like a single lexical word, rather than as a combination of `だれ + も`.  It has the same meaning either way, but since it's considered a single word, it can be marked with が.  But most of the other combinations are usually treated like `word + も` combinations, so you won't usually see them with が.  (It's been a while since I read about this, but hopefully I remembered correctly :-)

Answer (score 6):

This means "There isn't anything" or "Nothing is there", where "nothing/anything" has to be an animal or something living due to the use of `います`.  It's worth noting that it is **NOT** a "who", since both question and answer use `なに` instead of `だれ`.

You are correct that `も` is used for "also".  But it is used as a "negation" particle in the pattern `〜も〜ません`.  Here are some examples.

> - なにもいません／ありません　→　There is nothing (living/non-living) (there).
> - だれも来【き】ません　→　No one will come
> - なにもしませんでした　→　I didn't do anything
> - どこにもいきませんでした　→　He didn't go anywhere

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that meaning of mo. I'll research further!

Comment: So, in case of subject, が is omitted. I should say　なにもいません。　instead of　なにがもいません。 But in case of direction, に should be present. I should say どこにもいきませんでした。 instead of どこもいきませんでした。 Does this sound accurate?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I think technically `どこもいきませんでした` is correct, but adding the `に` really emphasizes the "to" of going somewhere -- "I did not go (to) somewhere".  Also, as `も` *replaces* the `は／が` in positive statements, it also replaces it in the negative, so it is not added on as `がも` (as you said).

Comment: Retract what I said about `も` replacing `が` all the time.  See @snailboat's (deleted) answer below.  There are times when you can say something like `だれもが` to mean "everyone", and similarly for other question words.  I forgot about this kind of scenario.